# Adding AJAX 'add to favorite' to this controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is blowing my mind, and there is so much going on that I just need to ask here for help.

Right now, I have a listing of resources. Inside each resource, it allows someone to 'add it as a favorite' by clicking a link. I have it working with normal redirection, but as for integrating ajax so they can favorite without the page refreshing, I am completely lost...

1. Right now I have it as a "put" action it seems for CRUD 'update'

FavoritesController (update is the only action in this controller)

```
  def update

    @favorite = Favorite.find_or_initialize_by_resource_id_and_user_id(params[:id], current_user.id)

    if @favorite.persisted?
      @favorite.destroy
    else
       if @favorite.valid?
          @favorite.save
       end
    end

    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= link_to "", favorites_path(:id => resource.id), :class => "star#{star_post?(resource)}", :method => "put" %>
```

My routes:

```
  resource :favorites, :only => [:update]
```

My JS:

```
  $('.res-list .star').click(function(){
    $.put('/favorites/?id=' + $(this).attr('data-id'));
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this.  You can use `link_to_function` through which you can pass a javascript method (you can even pass a custom one if you've defined it in the view or in application.js).  In this method, you can set up your AJAX call to hit your update action.

View (using jQuery's `put` macro):

```
<%= link_to_function "AJAX Link", "$.put('/favorites/#{resource.id}');" %>
```

Another way to do this is to give your link an addition HTML selector.  Again, you would need to write a bit of js to hit your update action.  I tend to like this way because I like to use buttons and what not instead of `<a href="#">` tags.  (Though honestly I ended up just creating a `button_to_function` method that calls `content_tag(:button)` instead of `content_tag(:a)`)

Comment: Thanks, I think I got some of that. Do I need to update my controller at all with respond_to?

Comment: Nope, your default format of HTML will be fine.  Your controller will redirect to the root url which would will render a page, but AJAX ignores all of that.  I guess you could have different `respond_to |format|` if you want to avoid that network hit.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I have a few super brief clarifications if you dont mind. I'm going with your second method I believe. So far I set up a JS function which captures the click event on the favorites link. Inside that I Have `$.put('/favorites/')` but how do I pass in the current ID? would I have to use something like a data attribute, read that, and insert it into the request?

Comment: Something like `$.put('/favorites/' + $(this).attr('foo'))` should do it.

Comment: I updated my original post with my JS. This is stupid question but... it still is redirecting normally. When I tried using link_to_function it did this as well. While it appears very briefly, i see 'no method error for put'

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend starting off with this Railscast on basic JQuery and Ajax processing. It's a bit dated, but is pretty solid still and will give you the basics to get you started.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery

It will give you an idea of how to attach the ajax call to the element on your page, handle request processing and craft a basic javascript view partial that will update the form for the user.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Also for Rails 3.1 see: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405688/rails-3-1-ajax-question